# Remove table row using javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, removechild

**remove**() doesn't work in IE11. Please provide any solution to the code below.

```
var TD1= document.getElementById('firstTbl').
        getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[4]; 
//This remove is not working in IE. 
firstTD1.remove();
```

*HTML* Code:

```
<table id="firstTbl">
<tr>
<td> <div class="stylediv">Basic </div> </td>                                      
<td> <div class="stylediv">Critical </div> </td>
<td> <div class="stylediv">Surgical </div> </td>
<td> <div class="stylediv">Hospital </div> </td>                
<td> <div class="stylediv">Waiver </div> </td>                        
</tr>                       
</table>
```

Note: Goal is to hide *Waiver* table row.

Comment: that code wont work **anywhere** because `firstTD1` is undefined - as for `Please provide any solution to the code below` - a simple google search would've resulted in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill) includes a polyfill for retarded, I mean old, browsers

Comment: You have the answer in your tags -- use `removeChild` instead of `remove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code snippet: working fine in IE and safari

```html
<html>
 <table id="firstTbl">
<tr>
<td> <div class="stylediv">Basic </div> </td>                                      
<td> <div class="stylediv">Critical </div> </td>
<td> <div class="stylediv">Surgical </div> </td>
<td> <div class="stylediv">Hospital </div> </td>                
<td> <div class="stylediv">Waiver </div> </td>                        
</tr>                       
</table>
<script>
var TD1= document.getElementById('firstTbl').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[4]; 
//This remove is not working in IE. 
console.log(TD1.parentNode);
TD1.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('td')[4]);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Method `remove` is not supported in all browsers:

Instead remove the element as follows:

```
var TD1 = document.getElementById('firstTbl').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[4]; 

TD1.parentNode.removeChild(TD1);
```

Comment: *Method remove is not supported in all browsers:* OP knows that, it's in the question :p